# Excel VBA Compact method to insert text in offset column based on FIND result

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a small timesaver tool that inserts various text values in a column based on a cell offset of the location of a list-based text search in column C.

`Dim C1 As Range 
Set C1 = Range("B:B").Find("Value to search") 
If C1 Is Nothing Then 
Else 
C1.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Text value to insert" 
End If`

I am certain there is a better way to write this relatively simple proc in a more scalable way rather than hard code each value to search in the code, but am not sure how this could be simplified further. I've been looking at the first two lines, and I may be wrong, but I believe a cell range needs to be defined as written in the first two lines in order for the Offset to know the cell location to offset from.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are planning on running this. You could have it as a sub that prompts a user to enter the search value and the text to input at offset. I show that below. It is easy enough instead to adapt to a loop if you have the search and offset strings in the sheet. I use only the populated area of column B for the search. The search values and insert/offset values are held in variables.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AddText()
    Dim searchValue As String, insertValue As String, C1 As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    searchValue = Application.InputBox("Please supply search value", Type:=2)
    insertValue = Application.InputBox("Please supply insert value", Type:=2)

    If searchValue = vbNullString Or insertValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'or loop prompting for entry

    With ws
        Set C1 = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Find(searchValue)
    End With
    If Not C1 Is Nothing Then C1.Offset(0, -1).Value = insertValue
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

From your comment you are actually just doing a VLOOKUP.

In sheet 2 A1 put the following and autofill down for as many rows as are filled in column B.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

---

Same thing using arrays and a dictionary

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddText()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim lookupArray(), updateArray(), lookupDict As Object, i As Long
    Set lookupDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With wsSource
        lookupArray = .Range("A1:B" & GetLastRow(wsSource, 1)).Value
    End With
    For i = LBound(lookupArray, 1) To UBound(lookupArray, 1)
        lookupDict(lookupArray(i, 1)) = lookupArray(i, 2)
    Next
    With wsSearch
        updateArray = .Range("A1:B" & GetLastRow(wsSearch, 2)).Value
        For i = LBound(updateArray, 1) To UBound(updateArray, 1)
            If lookupDict.Exists(updateArray(i, 2)) Then
                updateArray(i, 1) = lookupDict(updateArray(i, 2))
            End If
        Next
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(updateArray, 1), UBound(updateArray, 2)) = updateArray
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: For this purpose, the search values are predetermined and the value to insert will change based on the search value. Is it possible to base the searchValue on the contents of a worksheet rather than inputbox? ie): For each value in column A of Worksheet1, search for each value on Worksheet2 and if found, insert InsertValue from column B adjacent to value in Column A Worksheet1 in offset cell location on Worksheet2?

Comment: Thank you for the update, but the solution must be VB, a VLOOKUP does not quite achieve this result. The procedure must be able to find values in sheet1 column B from a list in column A sheet2 and when a match is found insert the value from column A sheet2 adjacent to that match in column B sheet2 into column A sheet1.

Comment: See vba version. You stated that you were searching column B so I have stuck with that.

Comment: Not quite, the values are not something the user will enter search terms for or use the scripting dictionary to find. The values to search for and the values to be inserted are both pre-determined. The most ideal setup I can think of using your code example would be to host a list of values in Sheet2 Column A, and for the procedure to search for each of those values in Sheet1 Column B and if a match is found for a value, the contents of the cell next to that value in Sheet 2 Column B are inserted into the cell adjacent to the match on Sheet1 Column A.

Comment: It's certainly close! The issue is that neither example uses the contents of Sheet2 Column A to provide the values to search for on Sheet1 Column B. The first example asks the user for input via a MsgBox and the second example uses the scripting dictionary. The procedure should ideally loop through Sheet1 Column B, search for the values provided in Sheet2 Column A procedurally, and if a match is found, insert the contents of the cell adjacent to the match in Sheet2 Column B next to the Match in Sheet1 Column A.

Comment: But the dictionary picks the values up from the sheet. It should do exactly the same thing. Perhaps it just the sheet/columns confused. I will add an image and then maybe you can help me understand how it is missing the mark.

Comment: Were you able to update the post with an image? Totally no rush. A separate issue with the code provided in the second dictionary example is that it appears to throw an error when run.